# Ruby metaprogramming - Multi line strings that doesn't try to evaluate the inner #{}

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, multiline

Is there any way to make multi line strings that doesn't try to evaluate the inner #{}
?

I want the following:

```
doc <<-DOC    
    describe "should get sysdate on test: #{test_name}" do
        it "should get SYSDATE" do
            conx_bd.sysdate.should_not == NULL
        end
    end    
DOC
```

to create a string (doc) with this content: (is for metaprogramming)

```
describe "should get sysdate on test: #{test_name}" do
    it "should get SYSDATE" do
        conx_bd.sysdate.should_not == NULL
    end
end
```

i'm getting this error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `test_name' for main:Object
```

if a surround the heredoc identifier with single quotes, i get this error if the string has for example a require

```
doc <<'-DOC'
require "spec_helper.rb" # conexión oracle

describe "should get sysdate on test: #{test_name}" do
    it "should get SYSDATE" do
        conx_bd.sysdate.should_not == NULL
    end
end
```

DOC

error:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- spec_helper
```

tks

EDIT:
Tks for your support, i get 2 possible solutions from the answers.

First i have an error defining the multi line string

```
doc <<-DOC should be <<-doc
```

1. scape # with \

   <<-doc
       describe "should get sysdate on test: #{test_name}" do
           it "should get SYSDATE" do
               conx_bd.sysdate.should_not == NULL
           end
       end
   doc
2. Surround the heredoc identifier with single quotes

   <<-'doc'
       describe "should get sysdate on test: #{test_name}" do
           it "should get SYSDATE" do
           conx_bd.sysdate.should_not == NULL
           end
       end
   doc

Comment: Sorry, but getting NameError in this situation means exactly that the string DOES try to evaluate its inner #{} and finds no local variable or method with name :test_name.

Comment: @d1egoaz I didn't read your comment carefully. See my edit on the answer. You can remove the added part from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the with the escape character before #. The escape character is `\`.

Answer (score 3):

Surround the heredoc identifier with single quotes.

```
doc <<-'DOC'    
    describe "should get sysdate on test: #{test_name}" do
        it "should get SYSDATE" do
            conx_bd.sysdate.should_not == NULL
        end
    end    
DOC
```

**Edit** I was wrong about the relative position of the single quote opening and the hyphen. steenslag was right. Fixed.

Comment: doc <<'-DOC'
require "spec_helper.rb" # conexión oracle

describe "should get sysdate on test: #{test_name}" do
        it "should get SYSDATE" do
            conx_bd.sysdate.should_not == NULL
        end
    end  
DOC    

if i put a require in the text, i'm getting this error:
    LoadError: no such file to load -- spec_helper

Comment: i get this error

NoMethodError: undefined method `-@' for "DOC":String

with a simple test:
doc = ''
doc <<-'DOC'
 test1
 test2
DOC


tks

Comment: i have an error defining the string
I only need to do:
<<-'doc'
doc

tks :) @sawa